# Excel formula for "select sum(B) where month(A)=3"

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2010

I have excel data as follows:

[image]

I want show the Total Cost for each month. 
I can achieve this in Google Spreadsheets with the following formula:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(COSTS!$1:$1101,"select sum(B) where month(A)=3"), 2)
```

Which gets the result for April.

But my requirement is now to do the same in Excel (which doesn't support the QUERY statements).

I have been playing around with SUMIF, but can't figure out how to make it work and not even sure if it's the right approach.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As column A is a date you will need something like this to test that the month is March(3), April(4) etc to match it, below is one way

ie for March

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH($A$1:$A$50)=3),$B$1:$B$50)`

for April
`=SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH($A$1:$A$50)=4),$B$1:$B$50)`

[image]

Comment: Brilliant thankyou. This did exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

I would first create an intermediary column containing the dates (`=Month(a1)` and copy down column B.

Then use the following:

`=SumIf(b1:b1101,"=4",c1:c1101)`

This assumes that the B column is where the month is held, and that the month is equal to 4.

Comment: The sample file shows that the column A data is a date - column A doesn't contain a `3` it contains `12\03\2011` etc. So your approach above won't work.

Comment: @brettdj, When I posted this answer, there was no sample (hence the comment in my answer). Thanks for letting me know information had been added.

Comment: It was in the dropbox link which has since been replaced by a sample picture

Comment: @brettdj, guess I just missed it then. The answer works now though.

Comment: I had meant to remove my downvote after your updated answer a few hours back, now done.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @soandos' approach , I would also use a helper column, and then build a pivot table with it.

You can use @soandos formula for the helper column, or you can use one like I've shown in the screen shot below.

[image]